# GPG not recognizing YubiKey 5 NFC on Windows 10

Tags: gnupg, yubikey

I am trying to setup a YubiKey 5 NFC with GPG on Windows 10 to ultimately use it to sign git-commits.

This is a new topic for me and I ran into some issues that got me stuck now.

I ran into this error:

```
gpg --card-status
gpg: selecting card failed: No such device
gpg: OpenPGP card not available: No such device
```

What I did so far to get a hold of the problem based on my online-research as this is a new topic for me:

- checked usb-interface-activation through the YubiKey Manager-Application (the card is being recognized and all interfaces are activated)
- created a scdaemon.conf in gpg's home-directory and tried to set the reader-port to either the name of the smartcard as seen in windows' device-manager smart-card-section and as seen in the list of connected USB-devices (to no effect)
- restarted the computer between tries until I found out the daemon can be reloaded via CLI
- enabled logging for scdaemon as I hoped that the reader-port string did just have a typo and I wanted to know if gpg at least detects the device in some way which it actually seems to do but fails connecting.

The log looks like this:

```
2021-05-05 11:17:02 scdaemon[942] listening on socket '/c/Users/nemo/.gnupg/S.scdaemon'
2021-05-05 11:17:02 scdaemon[942] handler for fd -1 started
2021-05-05 11:17:02 scdaemon[942] DBG: chan_7 -> OK GNU Privacy Guard's Smartcard server ready
2021-05-05 11:17:02 scdaemon[942] DBG: chan_7 <- GETINFO socket_name
2021-05-05 11:17:02 scdaemon[942] DBG: chan_7 -> D /c/Users/nemo/.gnupg/S.scdaemon
2021-05-05 11:17:02 scdaemon[942] DBG: chan_7 -> OK
2021-05-05 11:17:02 scdaemon[942] DBG: chan_7 <- OPTION event-signal=31
2021-05-05 11:17:02 scdaemon[942] DBG: chan_7 -> OK
2021-05-05 11:17:02 scdaemon[942] DBG: chan_7 <- GETINFO version
2021-05-05 11:17:02 scdaemon[942] DBG: chan_7 -> D 2.2.20-unknown
2021-05-05 11:17:02 scdaemon[942] DBG: chan_7 -> OK
2021-05-05 11:17:02 scdaemon[942] DBG: chan_7 <- SERIALNO
2021-05-05 11:17:02 scdaemon[942] detected reader 'Alcor Micro USB Smart Card Reader 0'
2021-05-05 11:17:02 scdaemon[942] detected reader 'Yubico YubiKey OTP+FIDO+CCID 0'
2021-05-05 11:17:02 scdaemon[942] reader slot 0: not connected
2021-05-05 11:17:02 scdaemon[942] pcsc_connect failed: removed card (0x80100069)
2021-05-05 11:17:02 scdaemon[942] reader slot 0: not connected
2021-05-05 11:17:02 scdaemon[942] DBG: chan_7 -> ERR 100696144 No such device <SCD>
2021-05-05 11:17:02 scdaemon[942] DBG: chan_7 <- RESTART
2021-05-05 11:17:02 scdaemon[942] DBG: chan_7 -> OK
2021-05-05 11:18:07 scdaemon[942] DBG: chan_7 <- GETINFO version
2021-05-05 11:18:07 scdaemon[942] DBG: chan_7 -> D 2.2.20-unknown
2021-05-05 11:18:07 scdaemon[942] DBG: chan_7 -> OK
2021-05-05 11:18:07 scdaemon[942] DBG: chan_7 <- SERIALNO
2021-05-05 11:18:07 scdaemon[942] detected reader 'Alcor Micro USB Smart Card Reader 0'
2021-05-05 11:18:07 scdaemon[942] detected reader 'Yubico YubiKey OTP+FIDO+CCID 0'
2021-05-05 11:18:07 scdaemon[942] detected reader ''
2021-05-05 11:18:07 scdaemon[942] reader slot 0: not connected
2021-05-05 11:18:07 scdaemon[942] pcsc_connect failed: removed card (0x80100069)
2021-05-05 11:18:07 scdaemon[942] reader slot 0: not connected
2021-05-05 11:18:07 scdaemon[942] DBG: chan_7 -> ERR 100696144 No such device <SCD>
2021-05-05 11:18:07 scdaemon[942] DBG: chan_7 <- RESTART
2021-05-05 11:18:07 scdaemon[942] DBG: chan_7 -> OK
2021-05-05 11:21:11 scdaemon[942] DBG: chan_7 <- killscd
2021-05-05 11:21:11 scdaemon[942] DBG: chan_7 -> OK closing connection
```

So I tried setting the reader-port in the config to "Yubico YubiKey OTP+FIDO+CCID 0" after reading that but that also didn't have any effect.

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm fighting the same thing right now and made it pretty much exactly as far as you. I'm assuming some other process is stealing the YubiKey out from under scdaemon, but I can't figure out what. Did you ever get any further with this?

Comment: Sorry for coming back to you after such a long time. Actually I was not able to solve this problem even after an elongated conversation with the YubiKey-support team which i must say did really put in some effort to help me, so kudos to them. Unfortunately due to outer circumstances I lacked time to pursue this any further. What I think i can say with at least some degree of confidence is that one of the company-preinstalled readers interferred with the process and I wasn't able to make it recognize the correct one.

Comment: Maybe I should add that my confidence derives from testing this against a non-company-pre-installed Ubuntu-system (20.04) on the same hardware and possibly even on my own hardware that didn't have any readers preinstalled (running Win10Prof) though I wouldn't want to swear on this as it has been several months since then. Result of the whole ordeal is that I got a really weird setup of a dual-boot-system running on my work-thinkpad to accomodate different project-needs. As you might not have such a weird presetup to deal with I would advise contacting yubi-support as they really tried to help.

Answer (score 1):

I was hitting a dead end like the others above.

Then I got it to work:

Opened a Powershell and:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-PnpDevice -Class SoftwareDevice | Where-Object {$_.FriendlyName -like "*YubiKey*"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FriendlyName
Yubico YubiKey OTP+FIDO+CCID 0
```

took that name "Yubico YubiKey OTP+FIDO+CCID 0" (it can vary per Yubikey model), and put that into

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\gnupg\scdaemon.conf

reader-port Yubico YubiKey OTP+FIDO+CCID 0
```

then I bounced the agent:

```
> gpg-connect-agent killagent /bye
> gpg-connect-agent /bye
```

After that, my command prompt could read the Yubikey when I did `gpg --card-status`. Also as an added bonus I saw I could manage the card in Kleopatra.

I suspect OP had it right but didn't restart the agent to pick up the changes in the scdaemon.conf.